# How to send a page_view event from an SPA (single page app) web app using Firebase Analytics?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, gtag.js

I have an SPA web app that I've built using React + Firebase.

I am now using Firebase Analytics and I would like to log `page_view` events for pages that are client-side routes (since I have my app is a Single Page App).

I didn't find anything about Single Page Apps in Firebase Analytics docs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events

But I did find something in the `gtag.js` docs.

**From:** https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications

[image]

---

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events#log_events_3

> You can find implementation details for several events and their parameters in the [gtag.js event reference](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event).

And from that event reference, we get that:

[image]

From the image above, we can see that the `page_view` event doesn't seem to have any parameter associated with it.

**QUESTION**

I can see that Firebase Analytics already sends the first `page_view` event, after my app is first loaded.

But once my users click on my internal links and change its browser URL (client side routed, no server calls), how can I trigger another `page_view` event for the new URL that was generated by `react-router-dom` ?

How can I implement this using Firebase Analytics? Do I need to update the page path before sending the event like it says on the `gtag.js` documentation? How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

Since your app is a single-page application, there is only a single `page_view` event. That is actually the correct behavior, because it means you can use `page_view` events to track how often the application/page was loaded.

When a specific screen is shown in your application, you'll want to fire a `screen_view` event. For an example of this, see the AngularFire library's documentation on [tracking screen views](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/0c5a1577b800082ef44b8e27aee966cfaa3082cc/docs/analytics/getting-started.md#tracking-screen-views).

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Please correct if I'm missing something, but over on `gtag.js` [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications) there is a section on how to send `page_view` events in a SPA. Isn't that different than sending `screen_view` events? How would I know where that view is coming from? Like which one of my page was the internal referrer for that new `page_view`? Is there something you can do with the `screen_view` event? Is it possible to do the same as `gtag.js` doc suggests, but using Firebase Analytics?

Comment: When I start my apps, I see an auto-logged `page_view`, and then one or more `screen_view` events that I log from my own application code. There I fully control the properties of the event, and can follow the flow quite well. I don't know if there's a way to explicitly log `page_view` events from your own code.

Comment: You are right. I guess it's possible to log `page_view` but it would mix up with the default `page_view` events that are sent by default. I think I found a way to do it with the `screen_view` events. Thanks a lot for your help!