# Is it possible to append data to the Firebase Analytics page_view event?

Tags: javascript, firebase-analytics

I've just begun using Firebase Analytics for my web app (JavaScript SDK). I've noticed it comes out-of-the-box with several logged event, some of which I've noticed: `page_view`, `first_visit`, `session_start`, `successful_login`.

**Is it possible to extend the bundle sent with each of these events with additional data?**

In my particular case, I'd like to include some user information to the `page_view` event.

That might look something like this:

```
const logEvent = (eventKey: string, myDataBundle: object) => {
    firebase.analytics().logEvent(eventKey, {
       ...myDataBundle, // Appended User Information
       ...defaultBundle,
    });
};
```

I could begin making my own `page_view` logs to Firebase Analytics in my app's router, but I suspect this would create duplicate `page_view` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to add custom parameters to the auto-fired `page_view` event. I typically instead fire `screen_view` events for the actual screens in the app. That also makes it easier to consistently track such views across web and native (iOS/Android) apps.

Also see:

- [How to send a page_view event from an SPA (single page app) web app using Firebase Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932980/how-to-send-a-page-view-event-from-an-spa-single-page-app-web-app-using-fireba)
- [Measuring virtual page views](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications#measure_virtual_pageviews)
- [App / Screen Measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/screens)